# My map shows but my markers dosnt in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

i have a fragment with a tab layout , so i slide to get into my map, when i get there it just opens the map but the markers dosnt show, my `MapActivity` is working good with the markers if i run it in a single activity, but how i can call the entire class in my tab layout fragment, here is what im doing

```
 else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3) {
                if(view3 == null) {
//                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
//                    view3 = rootView;

                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
                    mMapView = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
                    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

                    try {
                        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return v;


                } else {
                    return view3;
                }
```

it seems like it only opens the `activity_maps` but it dont open my `MapsActivity.class` entirely

this is what i get

[image: Not showing markers in my map]

thanks

Comment: You have to set the markers right? How do you expect them to be there without setting them?

Comment: @Eenvincible because i set them in my MapsActivity class, not there in the fragment, i just need to call my mapsactivity to execute in that tab layout

Comment: @ArmandoBarreda You can't use Activity code for a page in a ViewPager.  Take all of your code from MapsActivity, and integrate it into a Fragment that extends SupportMapFragment.

Comment: @DanielNugent yes we can, check the duplicate answer